# Evaluate a fit as a function of an argument

Tags: plotting, fitting

I'm trying to manipulate the following function:

```
R[e_, m_, B_, Nmax_] := 
  HeavisideTheta[e - Sqrt[m^2 + 2 B]]/(\[Pi] Sqrt[2 B])
    e (HurwitzZeta[1/2, (e^2 - m^2 - 2 B)/(2 B) - Nmax] - 
     HurwitzZeta[1/2, (e^2 - m^2 - 2 B)/(2 B) + 1]);

f[x_, B_] := 
 If[(x^2 - 1 - 2*B)/(2*B) - 1 >= 0, R[x, 1, B, 
   IntegerPart[(x^2 - 1 - 2*B)/(2*B) - 1]]];
```

So that for each value of `B`, I need a polynomial interpolation of `f[x,B]` (such an interpolation will be used inside an definite integral).

First, I construct a list in order to interpolate it. It looks like I have not troubles with the list definition for arbitrary values of `B`:

```
g0[B_] := 
  ParallelTable[
   If[(x^2 - 1 - 2*B)/(2*B) - 1 >= 0, {x, f[x, B]}, 
    Unevaluated@Sequence[]], {x, 0, 50, 0.1}];
```

But my problem is when I try to fit it. I mean, for a particular value of `B` all is OK, for example:

```
g = NonlinearModelFit[Evaluate@g0[10], a x^2 + b x + c, {a, b, c}, x]
Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, 20}]
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 20}]
```

but when I try to do:

```
g[B_] := NonlinearModelFit[Evaluate@g0[B], a x^2 + b x + c, {a, b, c},x];
Integrate[g[10][x], {x, 0, 20}]
Plot[g[10][x], {x, 0, 20}]
```

the integration is done, but the plot fails.

Do you can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check your code snippets.  I believe `f0` is not defined.  An error is raised that is different from the one you describe.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited it.